# Corda node fails to start with `Failed to create netty connection`

Tags: corda

When starting a Corda node, it failed to start up with the following error message:

```
core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection {}
```

Meanwhile, the node's webserver also failed to start with

```
internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {} cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
```

What is the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by a zombie Java process that is holding one of the ports your node is trying to start on.

Try killing it using `killall java -9` on osX, or `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete` on Windows.